# Can I use Ethernet to program Wi-Fi credentials on an Azure Sphere?

Tags: wifi, ethernet, azure-sphere

Is it possible to use Ethernet to set a user-provided Wi-Fi SSID and PSK on an Azure Sphere device in production? If so, how would I go about this, just speaking very generally? I'm looking for a solution to allow customers to set Wi-Fi credentials in the field, without adding BLE. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the device cannot be enabled for ethernet or BLE, then the only option is to connect the device to USB through a PC and configure the wifi manually.

Comment: My question was: is it possible to use Ethernet to set a user-provided Wi-Fi SSID and PSK. So, the Azure Sphere device will have Ethernet enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by loading the ethernet board config initially, so that it connects to Internet once deployed in the field. A cloud deployment needs to be created for the device to download the image with wifi info and connect to Internet.

Note: This assumes that all devices connect to same wifi or if the devices are deployed in different locations, they have the same wifi network ssid and psk.
Also for the device to connect to ethernet, all relevant ports are open on that particular n/w.

Creating board config - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/network/connect-ethernet?tabs=cliv2beta
Enabling Cloud Deployment - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/qs-first-deployment?tabs=cliv2beta

Comment: Thanks but we cannot assume that the field unit will have access to Ethernet, and each site will connect to a different Wi-Fi network, so they will not all have the same SSID and PSK.

Answer (score 0):

The "Azure Sphere - Private Network Services" code sample provides an example of how to communicate over a private network using only Ethernet. The Azure Sphere runs a DHCP server, and the client laptop connects to the Sphere over Ethernet. Then, the client uses Telnet to communicate directly with the Sphere over Ethernet. This can be used to provide the Wi-Fi SSID and PSK.